# Append safe HTML to unsafe HTML in Rails 3.2

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Suppose I have,

```
<%= @order.shipping.address1 + '<br />' unless @order.shipping.address1 %>
<%= @order.shipping.address2 + '<br />' unless @order.shipping.address2 %>
```

How can I return the variable with the default stripping of tags, and print the '
' as html_safe?

Presumably, wrapping in <%= raw ... %> would open up security issues with the variable not being stripped of html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use anything like raw or html_safe because it opens up vulnerabilities in the adress fields as you are rightfully saying.

You can just rewrite it like this:

```
<% unless @order.shipping.address1 %>
  <%= @order.shipping.address1 %> 
  <br />
<% end %>
<% unless @order.shipping.address2 %>
  <%= @order.shipping.address2 %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

But I would consider doing it with html/css instead of adding break lines. Surrounding it with a div will actually make the next element appear in the next line because a div is a [block element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) and thus creates a line wrap.

View:

```
<% unless @order.shipping.address1 %>
  <div>
    <%= @order.shipping.address1 %> 
  </div>
<% end %>
<% unless @order.shipping.address2 %>
  <div>
    <%= @order.shipping.address2 %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If you need further styling you can add a class and use css for width, height and other stuff.